# How do I implement a many-to-many association from an entity to itself in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have an entity that exposes a collection of children of the same type. The entity can itself be a child of another instance - in effect a many-to-many relationship with itself. In the database I have a linker table with two columns - parentId and childId - both of which reference the Id column in my entity table. Entity Framework correctly recognises that it is a many-tomany relationship with itself but throws an error:

> Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 249, 300: Two entities with possibly different keys are mapped to the same row. Ensure these two mapping fragments map both ends of the AssociationSet to the corresponding columns

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How are your Primary Keys setup?

Comment: the Id column in the main entity table and then a combination primary key consisting of the parentId and childId in the linker table..

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a many-to-many relationship in a new EF model and generate a database from that. Then compare the structures of what it created to your database model. This should give some clues.